# How many counts the square number?

Tags: math, delphi-7

For example I have a number is 55. Can I check this for how many counts number's square create this number.

For example I have 55 So, I know this number total from 5 number, which are

```
55 = 1^2+ 2^2+ 3^2+ 4^2 + 5^2(totally 5* number)
```

I found the counts is 5 for 55 . How can I found counts any number. Is there any formula or equation? I dont want to know which number's square. I just want to know how many numbers squares create this number. In my example my answer is 5. but If I can calculate this 10 digit any number its too complex.

For example if my number was 652369. How can I found how many numbers square total from? I just want to find how many number. I m sorry my english. I m using Delphi programming language.

Note: The numbers are not "consecutive" everytime.

Comment: This seems like a better question for http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I know just here. I used this web site everytime. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [math.se]. It is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: *I know just here. I used this web site everytime.* That doesn't make it right. You should learn about the other [se] sites, and post to the one that is proper for your question. There are different sites because questions are about different things; posting every question to a single site because it's the only one you know is not proper.

Comment: I wrote my question to math.stackexchange. OK:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a closed-form formula for the sum of the first n squares:

```
1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
```

To answer your question, you have to "invert" the function above; in other words, you need to solve the equation

```
n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 = 55 or 2n^3 + 3n^2 + n - 330 = 0
```

One way to solve equations like that is by using Newton's method. We have

```
f(n) = 2n^3 + 3n^2 + n - 330
f'(n) = 6n^2 + 6n + 1
```

Then you make an initial guess (e.g., `n_0 = (330/2)^(1/3)` because 3 is the dominant power) and improve that guess using the formula

```
n_(k+1) = n_k - f(n_k)/f'(n_k)
```

You can terminate the algorithm when the change from `n_k` to `n_(k+1)` is small enough.

I don't know Delphi so here is an implementation in Java.

```
public class SumOfSquares {
  public static double f(double x) {
    return ((2*x+3)*x+1)*x;
  }

  public static double fp(double x) {
    return (6*x+6)*x+1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int target = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    double guess = Math.pow(target/2.0,1/3.0);
    double epsilon = 0.00001;

    double x0, x1;
    x1 = guess;
    do {
      x0 = x1;
      x1 = x0 - (f(x0)-6*target)/fp(x0);
    } while (Math.abs(x0-x1)>epsilon);

    System.out.println(x1);

    // check                                                                    
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=Math.floor(x1); i++) {
      sum += i*i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

`java SumOfSquares 55` prints out 5.0, and checks the sum of squares up to 5^2 is 55. `java SumOfSquares 652369` prints out 124.5855... which indicates that 652369 isn't exactly a sum of squares. The sum of squares below it is 643250.

Comment: I m sorry I did not understand. Can u find the counts for 652398. How can u find  can u show me on example?